# How can I print multiple tables side by side in one job?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, jframe

How can I print three different tables side by side or add them together in one printing? since the following code prints separately and in different pages.
I have little knowledge with the printing aspect of `JTable`'s.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.

Or could I instead import the data to an excel file and print it from there? Is that plausible?
edit: All three tables must be together, side by side when it print, regardless if its portrait or landscape. Even better if all the tables or joined and is represented by multiple columns instead of three separate tables.

```
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
 PrintRequestAttributeSet asset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
 PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(asset);
 job.setPrintable(new recording_system(), pf);
 boolean ok = job.printDialog(asset);
 if (ok) {
     try {
         jTstudents.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL);
         jTscores.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL);
         jTresults.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL);
     } catch (PrinterException ex) {
         /* The job did not successfully complete */
     }
}
```

The tables look like this
[image: Student Recording System]

Comment: It looks to me like your best bet might be to use a dedicated reporting library, and if cost is an issue, some open-source solutions are available and can be found via Google.

Comment: Are you using netbeans

Comment: Ah, yes, i am indeed usng netbeans 8.0

Comment: Please clarify whether you want the table views as illustrated or the table model data. See also [*How to Print Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html).

Comment: Ah, yes, I have tried that but with my current knowledge of Java, I wasn't able to print the tables side by side, since the data per row are related, in other words, the three tables are connected. From ID to Remarks.

Comment: You can make one JTable with a JTableModel child, combining the jTStudents.getModel(), jTScores.getModel() and jTResults.model. Do not forget `asset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, that seems plausible, although I am unfamiliar with the specific codes, will you please refer me somewhere where i can study it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a TableModel class that combines all models.

```
TableModel model = new ParallelTableModel(jTStudents.getModel(),
                                          jTScores.getModel(),
                                          TResults.getModel());
JTable totalTable = new JTable(model);
```

Copy table header.
And then [totalTable.getPrintable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) for printing.

```
/**
 * Table Model composed from side-by-side table models.
 */
public class ParalleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final TableModel[] models;

    public ParalleTableModel(TableModel... models) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return models[0].getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            count += model.getColumnCount();
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            int n = model.getColumnCount();
            if (columnIndex < count) {
                return model.getColumnName(columnIndex - count);
            }
            count += n;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            int n = model.getColumnCount();
            if (columnIndex < count) {
                return model.getColumnClass(columnIndex - count);
            }
            count += n;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            int n = model.getColumnCount();
            if (columnIndex < count) {
                return model.isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex - count);
            }
            count += n;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            int n = model.getColumnCount();
            if (columnIndex < count) {
                return model.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex - count);
            }
            count += n;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        for (TableModel model : models) {
            int n = model.getColumnCount();
            if (columnIndex < count) {
                model.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex - count);
            }
            count += n;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but since I wasn't familiar with tablemodels, I simply got rid of the errors that was displayed but i tried running it and i received an exception:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel

Comment: Check the stacktrace, the line number, and check when the models are created, set and gotten. Probably does not happen in right order. Alternatively you could make a tab separated file, with Excel extension .xls and call `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` Or even `print`.

Comment: Well i replaced some codes with
`totalTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
TableModel model = new ParallelTableModel(jTstudents.getModel(), jTscores.getModel(),jTresults.getModel());
JTable totalTable = new JTable(model);
totalTable.setModel(model);`
but, totalTable still comes up blank

Comment: If the other tables are still not filled, that would explain it. Set the model late. Sorry.